# How to set global variable as pxcor or pycor of a patch?

Tags: netlogo

I want to save the location of the next patch to use as a global variable so I can refer back to it, like in `position-shift` so I can alter it in case it is near the edge of the world. However, the code I am using to execute whatever the patch does is in `observer` mode with set-position and position-shift incorporated in it.

An error shows that `patch-at` is in turtle/patch-only context while `set-position` in observer context.

(Not sure but would similar error come up for `position-shift`?)

`to set-position
    set nextXcor [pxcor] of patch-at 0 -5
    set nextYcor [pycor] of patch-at 0 -5
    position-shift
end`

`to position-shift
    if nextYcor = -15
      [set nextXcor [pxcor] of patch-at 3 30
      set nextYcor [pycor] of patch-at 3 30]
    if nextXcor = 15 and nextYcor = -15
    [user-message "Space limit reached. Press Halt to continue." stop]
end`

**Q:** How should I approach fixing the code for `set-position` and potentially `position-shift` so global variables `nextXcor` and `nextYcor` can save the location of the next patch to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is generally preferable to work directly with patches when that is feasible.

```
globals [nextPatch]

to test
  ;first test
  set nextPatch one-of patches
  position-shift
  ;second test
  set nextPatch (patch 0 -15)
  position-shift
  ;third test
  set nextPatch (patch 15 -15)
  position-shift
end

to position-shift
  if ([pycor] of nextPatch = -15) [
    if ([pxcor] of nextPatch = 15) [
      user-message "Space limit reached. Press 'OK' to continue or 'Halt' to stop." 
    ]
    set nextPatch (patch 3 10)
  ]
  ;remove the next line
  print nextPatch
end
```